# How to comment and uncomment multiple erb lines using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems there is no way to comment and uncomment erb files using Visual Studio Code. I wonder if it is any extension out there. Actually I tried almost every code I found on the internet.

I tried the extension [Ruby on Rails support for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/bung87/vscode-rails), but couldn't figure out how to uncomment multiple lines. Any hint appreciated.

Comment: Which extension are you using to support erb files?

Comment: Currently I'm not using any extension. Just looking for one.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77922877/836330 - you can comment multiple lines with that ruby extension.  And if you want to make a change to the comment style see the extension demo'ed there.

Answer (score -2):

try `ctrl + /` after select to comment/uncomment multiple line of code.

Comment: Hi @Soumik Maity. It isn't working with erb files.