# In VScode how can I change what the shortcut "command + /" outputs in a .erb file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my VScode, on mac, when using the commentLine shortcut "command+/", in an html.erb file, instead of commenting out the line with an html `<!-- comment -->` it wraps the highlighted code in a `<% begin %>` `<% end %>` block. How can I change the behaviour of VScode's "editor.action.commentLine" function, which is what I believe this keyboard shortcut triggers, to insert the desired html comment tag?

Comment: the language json file defines the comment delimeters, change the language ID, status bar right

Comment: For other function and shortcut reasons I want the correctly set (html.erb) language for html.erb files to remain set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the text you want and press `ctrl+/` or `command+/`

You can define the following key binding:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+/",  // or command+/ for Mac
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorHasSelection && editorLangId == erb",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.*)$/<!-- $1 -->/}"
    }
  }
```

Maybe you have to change the languageID: `erb`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I found was to within VSCode's 'language-configuration-erb.json' file (found at `/Users/<your_username>/.vscode/extensions/bung87.rails-0.17.8/language-configuration-erb.json`) make this change:

*(mac–'command+shift+p', then type name to find the above file)*

```
{
    "comments": {
        "blockComment": [
            // "<%\n=begin%>\n",
            // "\n<%\n=end%>"
            "<!--",
            "-->"
        ]
    },
...
}
```

Comment: the next time you get an extension update you lose the modification

Answer (score 0):

I updated my extension, [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax) to handle language ID's like `html.erb`.

First, since rails is **NOT** one of the languages supported out of the box by vscode run the command

```
Custom Language Properties: Check for new language extensions
```

so the extension can build the relevant files it needs.

By the way, you can also see the default language configuration file for the active editor by using this command:

```
Custom Language Properties: Show language configuration for current editor
```

and edit that file to make the same comment or bracket changes you want and not make any setting as mentioned below.  But I suggest you do not do that as you will have to re-do it if the rails extension is updated.

With the extension you can easily modify the language configuration file for your chosen language with a setting (in your `settings.json` file) like:

```json
  "custom-language-properties": {
    "html.erb.comments.blockComment": ["<!--","-->"]
  }
```

[image: making a custom language configuration setting]

Then the comment style is automatically changed.  And updates to that rails extension will not require you to change anything again.

And it works as a toggle - so you can toggle the comments on or off with the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> shortcut.

[image: custom comments in html.erb]